# jscience Real comparison returns false even though values are equal

Tags: java, comparison, jscience

Here is my code:

```
Real AB = adj[a].get(b);
System.out.println("AB " + AB);
Real AC = adj[a].get(c);
System.out.println("AC " + AC);
Real BC = adj[b].get(c);
System.out.println("BC " + BC);
System.out.println(AB.plus(BC));
System.out.println(AB.plus(BC).equals(AC));
```

And here is the output:

```
AB 2.2360679775
AC 6.7082039325
BC 4.4721359550
6.7082039325
false
```

Even though the numbers are identical, why does it return false? I have also tried

```
System.out.println(AB.plus(BC).compareTo(AC) == 0);
```

Again, `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `equals()` implementation for `Real` checks for identical significand, error and exponent. Instead, use `approximates()`, which "takes into account possible errors (e.g. numeric errors)."

Addendum: See also these articles as regards floating point comparison:

- [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)
- [*What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](http://floating-point-gui.de)